# How to get last record from single group

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by

I have following type of table.I want to output of last record(most recent) of particular group.Please suggest My sql query.

```
    Id Name    random number
    -------------------------
    1   A         1233
    2   A         1778
    3   A         1221
    4   B         1298
    5   B         1289
    6   C         1267
```

I want a last record of group A

e.g.

```
        ID  Name  Random number
       ----------------------
        3    A      1221
```

Answer (score 5):

```
select id, name, random from table where Name='A' order by id desc limit 1
```

Comment: This is not OP requirement. OP want to get the record of all group above is only example.

Comment: @Broken Heart ღ: "of **particular** group"

Comment: @Broken Heart ღ: right. That's what exactly OP asked: "I want a last record of group A"

Comment: Hey i have clear that i want only last record of group A

Answer (score 2):

Here is query :

```
select * from tbl where id IN (select max(id) from tbl group by name);
```

And here is fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01d69/8

Comment: It's an overkill solution. OP asked about a particular group explicitly.

Comment: @OP asked for a particular group  so the first answer is right OP does'nt ask for last row per group,also zerkms is right subquery will reduce the performance

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * From Table1 Where [Id] in (
SELECT Max([Id]) as [maxId] From Table1 Where [Name] = 'A')
```

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fb508c/9)**

Comment: This is not OP requirement. OP want to get the record of all group above is only example.

Comment: @Broken Heart ღ: who told you that?

Comment: @Broken Heart ღ: so? it's an output for the given requirement "I want a last record of group A". If OP wanted the last row for every group they would ask about last row for every group, not for a **particular** group.

Comment: Hey @BrokenHeartღ i want query just get last record of group A